# How to import / export database with field MEDIUMBLOB?

Tags: php, backup, blob

I am developing a system where the user can register and search for images. These images are saved in a table that has a field MEDIUMBLOB.

The problem I have starts with the fact that the system must also make a backup of the database, that is, it will also need to export and import data.

When I do the backup, for example, a table which only has "regular" fields (such as varchar, int, date) the [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) script can perform the backup normally, but when I try to back up the table where the field type is MEDIUMBLOB, it returns an error.

Is there a way to backup the database using PHP, for a table containing a MEDIUMBLOB field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved my problem! The solution was at the time of registration of the image. It was necessary to convert it to base64_encode. With this [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) script I could generate an INSERT correctly, precisely because the string does not contain any special characters.